# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties" when bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, bundle-install

I searched the SO, there are several related question, but can not solve my issue.

When I run: `$ bundle update`

> Fetching gem metadata from https://gems.ruby-china.org/..........
>       Fetching version metadata from https://gems.ruby-china.org/..
>       Resolving dependencies...
>       Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
>         In Gemfile:
>           devise (~> 3.5.0) was resolved to 3.5.1, which depends on
>             railties (< 5, >= 3.2.6)
>           rails (~> 5.0.1) was resolved to 5.0.1, which depends on
>             railties (= 5.0.1)

The picture is below:

[image]

And, I run `$ rails -v`:

> Could not find gem 'devise (~> 3.5.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.

Comment: Check your Gemfile and make sure it says `gem 'devise'` and not `gem 'devise', '~> 3.5.0'`.

Comment: @jvillia, I'd recommend always controlling the version of gems, to prevent uncontrolled updates, at least to not jump to a new major version.

Comment: Fair enough. It's not a practice I regularly follow - except of course when building gems (and I've been lucky so far, I guess). But, it's a good recommendation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have fixed your version of devise to be a '3.5.x' version, which  is incompatible with rails 5. In your Gemfile you will need to change the version of devise that you use, probably to a 4.x version, as 3.5, like this:

`gem 'devise', '~> 3.5.0'`

should become

`gem 'devise', '~> 4.1.0'`

or something like that.